# groovy spock prints stacktrace though exception is catched

Tags: groovy, junit, spock

I have a spock test, which calls some service:

```
when:
def x = service.call()

then:
!x
```

Inside service I have:

```
def call() {
  try {
    doCall() // method, which throws an exception
  } catch (e) {
    false
  }
}
```

So I expect method to return `false` and test to pass. However, test invocation from IDE prints stacktrace of the exception, though it is catched.

Purpose of the test is not to know whether exception was thrown, but just assert returned result is false, so I don't want to use `Specification.thrown`

Comment: what exception do you have? `catch(e)` catches only Exception and descendants.

Comment: My exception is `GroovyRuntimeException`

Comment: Btw, post a full stack trace please. Otherwise it is impossible to guess what might be the real cause of the issue.

Comment: What Spock version, Groovy version an Java version are you using? In Spock 1.1 and 1.2 under Java 8 the behavior is correct. And as @SzymonStepniak said - post also the full stack trace.

Comment: The problem is in `groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder:494` (0.7.1 version). It prints warn message and passes caught exception there, which prints stacktrace and then rethrows it

Answer (score 0):

First of all - check what specific exception gets thrown and gets outside the `try-catch` block. You have to be aware that following code in Groovy:

```groovy
try {
   // do something
} catch (e) {
   // do something with exception
}
```

is an equivalent of:

```groovy
try {
   // do something
} catch (Exception e) {
   // do something with exception
}
```

It means that `java.lang.Throwable` and all its children classes (except `java.lang.Exception`) are not caught inside your try catch. For instance:

```
def call() {
    try {
        throw new Error('Something wrong happened')
    } catch (e) {
        false
    }
}
```

This exception won't get caught by `try-catch` and you will see something like this in the console log:

```
java.lang.Error: Something wrong happened

    at com.github.wololock.micronaut.TestSpec$Service.call(TestSpec.groovy:22)
    at com.github.wololock.micronaut.TestSpec.test(TestSpec.groovy:13)
```

It happens, because `java.lang.Error` extends `java.lang.Throwable` and it is not a child class of `java.lang.Exception`.

If you want to catch all possible exceptions that may happened to your code you would have to use `Throwable` inside the catch block, something like this:

```
def call() {
    try {
        throw new Error('Something wrong happened')
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        false
    }
}
```

Comment: My exception is of type `GroovyRuntimeException`, which is a child of `Exception`

Comment: I think it is spock-related, as when I just run app, not tests, exception is caught and  there is no stacktrace

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. Throwing `GroovyRuntimeException` from the same place as `doCall()` method is being called gets caught by `try-catch` correctly. 
 Check the implementation of `doCall` method. Maybe you have some kind of `try-catch` applied there so it catches the exception and prints stacktrace inside the method. Alternatively, double check if the exception you see is nothing else than `GroovyRuntimeException`. It may happen that `GroovyRuntimeException` is nested inside other `Throwable` and then it is not caught by your `try-catch`.